# how to enable menu button below my activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-actionbar

1 question: How to enable menu button below my activity as shown in images. because action bar i have already disabled. Action bar i dnt have use in my app so i disabled it. currently i am using linear layout as my bar.. i want to enable only menu as shown in images. plz help me guys.. thanks u in advance.

currently i am using whole application action bar disable.

```
      <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar">
```

currently android version 11.. 
In mainfest.xml

```
       <application
       android:icon="@drawable/mplebicon"
       android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
          android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

[image]

```
                                 OR
```

2 question:  i am not using action bar in my app...i made it disable in this way

```
           <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar">
```

My question is how to enable only menu in my actvity in linear layout or any layout. I dnt want that default menu in action bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of unclear, do you want the Action bar at the bottom to always be visible? If so then you shouldn't need to do anything in android. Just remove the top bar by using:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

I would read through http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html and get a complete understanding of action bars from there. If you could give some more detailed information on what you're trying to do then that would be nice :)

Comment: i am not using action bar in my app...i made it disable in this way <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar">. My question is how to enable only menu in my actvity in linear layout. I dnt want that default menu in action action bar.